# Flandmark in Android

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have a desktop version of the [Flandmark](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv-examples/tree/master/flandmark-demo) code and I planned to implement them into an Android version. Do you think I could reuse the dependencies (jar files) that is downloaded using SBT (OpenCV, JavaCV) into Android. Would it be compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be no problem:

1. You should put your `.jar` Files in the `libs` folder
2. Right click on it and select 'Add as library
3. Ensure that `compile files('libs/*.jar')` is in your `build.gradle` file
4. And then update Gradle